# Cucumber on JDK 11

Tags: java, cucumber-java, azul-zulu

I was trying to find out if Cucumber can still run on JDK 11. We are currently using Azul Zulu JDK 8 on one of our applications and been using Cucumber as testing tool. If not, then can I know if there are some other alternatives for for Cucumber which can run in JDK 11? Thanks!

Comment: As per official tutorial, it is not supported https://docs.cucumber.io/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Cucumber 10 Minute Tutorial](https://docs.cucumber.io/guides/10-minute-tutorial/):

> Before we begin, you will need the following:
>
> - Java SE (Java 9 and higher are not yet supported by Cucumber)

It looks like Java 9+ is not supported yet. It looks like [JGiven](https://github.com/TNG/JGiven) may support Java 11.

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber runs fine with Java 11.  I'm doing so.

See also https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1557